# Issues with scripts published as a service

Tags: google-apps-script

This issue has been reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563356/scripts-published-as-public-services-are-down) and has been closed. I do see that there is currently a problem with publishing scripts as a service. Previously published scripts work fine but not able to publish new scripts as a service.

When the service URL is put into a browser, the following error is shown

> Google Docs has encountered a server error. If reloading the page doesn't help, please >contact us.
>
> To discuss this or other issues, visit the Google Docs Help forum. To see the list of >known problems, check the Google Docs Known Issues page.
>
> Sorry, and thanks for your help!
>   - The Google Docs Team

The Apps Script dashboard shows all services as running ok. 
One such example is https://docs.google.com/macros/exec?service=AKfycbypKC46e9mIpPerpki3iNfWYJb0IPnKLXq16IOJag

I was able to publish other scripts as a service without issues.

Comment: Just did a quick test myself, and was able to run a script as a service. Without seeing your code, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: I could also publish it normally. There's no problems with scripts as services. Please post your code!

Comment: The problem looks to be resolved now. I'm able to view the UI without any errors now. The code, wasnt any great

Comment: Stack Overflow is designed for Q&A content. Bug reports should be posted to the Google Apps Script issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have been resolved. I'm not seeing the error anymore for the same script. 
The code itself isn't great

```
function doGet(e){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication(); 
  app.add(app.createLabel('Hello World'));
  return app;
}
```

When I had the problem, the problem wasn't seen for every script I created. One of the scripts randomly had this error showing up.

Comment: There is an issue open for this http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1336

Answer (score 0):

The issue is still not resolved. I just did a quick test on customer domain as well as on our domain.

When you publish service as public (anonymous access) services are down. It's been so since yesterday...

---

Update: Today I've fixed the issue. It seems that something has changed how response is handled. As there is no way how to send just plain html/json back to the caller, we used 'throw' clause with some information that propagates back to the client.

After changing code from this:

```
function doGet(e) {
    throw 'HTTP get not supported.';
}
```

to this:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication(); 
  app.add(app.createLabel('HTTP get not supported.'));
  return app;
}
```

and the same for doPost method, the published service works now.